# Align rows in two fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to align "rows" inside two fragments.

One my Activity display use two fragments who display related contents :

```
|EnvironmentActivity             |
||KeysFragment ||ValuesFragment ||
||[TextView]   ||[EditText]     ||
```

I would like to align both the 'KeysFragment -> TextViews' and 'ValulesFragment -> EditTexts'. I have naively tried to fix heights and margins but that is not working well and the result is varying between devices (screens, layouts and version).

**Edit** *Apr. 8 2014 15:36*

Another difficulty is that each "row" (KeysFragment -> TextView, ValuesFragment -> EditText) is added programmatically.

What is the best way to align rows inside diffrent layouts ?

Comment: I'm not really sure if it's doable if you're using 2 different fragments...

Comment: That is also my impression. But I'm doing that to avoid recreating the 'KeysFragment' who never changes while the 'ValuesFragment' is contained inside a SwipeView

Answer (score 0):

I think you shold take look on your layot and check if controls have enaugh space, try to use similary compesed layouts and control sizes, Your container layout perhaps would be linear, so you can use weights.